# Figure out if child element is outside parent element

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to figure out if a child element is visible in the parent element. By doing this I am testing if the `width` of the parent is bigger or smaller then the childs `position().left`.

Since I have many separate parent elements and child elements, I run `each` functions.

```
//Each p in instagram feed
jQuery('#instagram-feed .meta-data p').each(function(){

    // Get width of this p element
    var parentWidth = jQuery(this).width();

    // Each a element within this p
    jQuery(this).children('a').each(function(){

        // Compare p element width of with position of this a
        if(parentWidth < jQuery(this).position().left) {

            // If position is larger then width
            jQuery(this).css('color', 'green');
            console.log("Not inside element");

        } else {

            // If position is smaller then width
            jQuery(this).css('color', 'red');
            console.log("Inside element");
        }

        console.log(jQuery(this).position().left);

    });

});
```

I have made a fiddle so you can see and test: http://jsfiddle.net/fprm7mgd/9/ (Make sure the three elements are horizontal to see the "bug")

[image]

The problem is that in the third parent element, it seems like `position().left` counts from the first parent, or above parent. Why does the link in the third parent becomes green? Since it is inside the parent it should be red... What have I done wrong?

Comment: In this case `position().left` always count from first element that is initial position. the link which becomes green, for that parent width is less than position.left width.

Comment: *"Why does the link in the third parent becomes green?"* -- It is red in your fiddle! I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Not in my fiddle @Abhitalks, added screenshot above. Ok, so if it counts `position().left` from the first parent, how do I change so it counts from the parent the `a` is inside?

Comment: @JoakimB: See this - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/fprm7mgd/31/ (*no jquery just plain javascript*)

Comment: @Abhitalks - It seems to work, but I really do not understand it. I am more familar with jQuery, so I guess I use the answer below.

Comment: @JoakimB: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution:

```
//This will only work properly if margin-left and margin-right is equal. Same for padding.
function removefromTabindex(myElement, ellipsisSize){

    var ellipsisSizeInit = ellipsisSize;
    if (ellipsisSizeInit === undefined || ellipsisSizeInit === null) {
        ellipsisSizeInit = 0;
    }

    jQuery(myElement).each(function(){
        var myMargin = (jQuery(this).outerWidth(true) - jQuery(this).width()) / 2;
        myMargin = myMargin + ellipsisSizeInit;
        var parentRight = (jQuery(this).position().left + jQuery(this).outerWidth(true)) - myMargin;

        jQuery(this).find('a').each(function(){
            if((jQuery(this).position().left) > parentRight) {
                jQuery(this).attr('tabindex', '-1');
            } else {
                if ( jQuery(this).attr('tabindex') === '-1') {
                    jQuery(this).removeAttr('tabindex')
                }
            }
        });

    });

};

//Run function
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    removefromTabindex('#instagram-feed .meta-data p');
});

//For a responsive view
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    removefromTabindex('#instagram-feed .meta-data p');
});
```

This covers paddings and margins, but only work properly when margin and padding are equal on left and right side, since I have not found any perfect way to get margin and padding as int pixels (If margin is set by percent or ems). I have to calculate margin and padding by inner and outer width of the element.

It loads at start but also on resize to make sure it re-counts the values in a responsive design. It is now also possible to add more elements to the function by the param. Also added ellipsis width as a param so you can add that width to the calculation.

By using this script you can use CSS-shortning of texts and remove overflowing links from tab-index, which may be a great thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/fprm7mgd/46/

Answer (score 3):

You could use `jQuery(this).position().left - parent.position().left` to calcualte the left of the `a` element, something like this:

```
//Each p in instagram feed
jQuery('#instagram-feed .meta-data p').each(function(){

    // Get width of this p element
    var parentWidth = jQuery(this).width();
    var parent = jQuery(this);

    // Each a element within this p
    jQuery(this).children('a').each(function(){

        var elementLeft = jQuery(this).position().left - parent.position().left;
        // Compare p element width of with position of this a
        if(parentWidth < elementLeft) {

            // If position os larger then width
            jQuery(this).css('color', 'green');
            console.log("Not inside element");

        } else {

            // If position os smaller then width
            jQuery(this).css('color', 'red');
            console.log("Inside element");
        }

        // ...

    });

});
```

See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fprm7mgd/29/

Comment: This is working, and I actually thought about this solution yesterday. But also thought "There most be a better solution, I most have done something wrong in the each-loops". :)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation of [`jQuery.position`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) you will notice that the position is *relative to the [offset parent](https://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/)*. The offset parent in your example is the `<html>` element and all left values are relative to that element.

The solution is to add a minor tweak to your CSS: make the paragraph elements `position: relative`.

```js
jQuery(window).on("load resize", function() {
  jQuery("#instagram-feed .meta-data p").each(function() {
    var parentWidth = jQuery(this).width();
    console.log("parent", this, "width", parentWidth);
    jQuery(this).children("a").each(function() {
      var childLeft = jQuery(this).position().left;
      console.log("child", this, "left", childLeft, "offset parent", this.offsetParent);
      if (parentWidth < childLeft) {
        jQuery(this).css("color", "green");
      } else {
        jQuery(this).css("color", "red");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.meta-data {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
p {
  width: 160px;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: silver;
  display: inline-block;
  /* added */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="instagram-feed">
  <div class="meta-data">
    <p>fgdfgfdg fdgf df df <a href="#">link</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="meta-data">
    <p>fgdfgfdg fdgf df df dsfsdf <a href="#">link</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="meta-data">
    <p>fgdfgfdg fdgf <a href="#">link</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the information. This is absolutely what I was looking for. Cleanest solution. And thanks for clarifying the "offset position". `position: relative` on the paragraphs did the job. Great to only use css to fix the last part. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You should be using `offset` instead of `position` to be on a safer side. That is because as per http://api.jquery.com/offset/ :

> The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an
>   element relative to the document. Contrast this with .position(),
>   which retrieves the current position relative to the offset parent

2. The `offset` or `position` returns an object with `left` and `top` properties. What you really need to compare is the `left` of anchor with the `right` of parent. So, just add the `width` of the parent to its `offset().left`. Now compare it with the anchor's `left`.

Like this:

```
$('#instagram-feed .meta-data').each(function(){
    var parentRight = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width();
    $(this).find('a').each(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        if(self.offset().left > parentRight) {
            self.css('color', 'green');
        } else {
            self.css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/fprm7mgd/33/**

**Demo Snippet:**

```js
$('#instagram-feed .meta-data').each(function(){
    var parentRight = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width();
    $(this).find('a').each(function(){
  var self = $(this);
        if(self.offset().left > parentRight) {
            self.css('color', 'green');
        } else {
            self.css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.meta-data {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

p {
    width: 160px;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: silver;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="instagram-feed">
    <div class="meta-data">
        <p>
            fgdfgfdg fdgf df df <a href="#">link</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="meta-data">
        <p>
            fgdfgfdg fdgf df df dsfsdf <a href="#">link</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="meta-data">
        <p>
            fgdfgfdg fdgf <a href="#">link</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Even better solution would be to just use the Javascript [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method, which returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

```
var parents = document.querySelectorAll('.meta-data');
[].forEach.call(parents, function(elem) {
    var parentBounds = elem.getBoundingClientRect(), 
        anchor = elem.getElementsByTagName('A')[0], 
        anchorBounds = anchor.getBoundingClientRect()
    ;
    if (anchorBounds.left > parentBounds.right) {
        anchor.classList.add('red');
    } else {
        anchor.classList.add('green');
    }
});
```

**Demo Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/n0ak4y7w/**

**Demo Snippet 2:**

```js
var parents = document.querySelectorAll('.meta-data');

[].forEach.call(parents, function(elem) {
    var parentBounds = elem.getBoundingClientRect(), 
        anchor = elem.getElementsByTagName('A')[0], 
        anchorBounds = anchor.getBoundingClientRect()
    ;
    if (anchorBounds.left > parentBounds.right) {
        anchor.classList.add('green');
    } else {
        anchor.classList.add('red');
    }
});
```

```css
.meta-data {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

p {
    width: 160px;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: silver;
    display: inline-block;
}

.red { color: #f00; }
.green { color: #3c3; }
```

```html
<div id="instagram-feed">
    <div class="meta-data">
        <p>
            fgdfgfdg fdgf df df <a href="#">link</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="meta-data">
        <p>
            fgdfgfdg fdgf df df dsfsdf <a href="#">link</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="meta-data">
        <p>
            fgdfgfdg fdgf <a href="#">link</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I end up using your first suggestion instead, with a small modification. I am using `outerWidth(true)` instead of `width()`, to make sure to include paddings and margins. I will add "final solution" as the answer, but it is based on your first suggestion. By doing this, I do not need to add `position: relative;` to each element where I wanna do this.